# Some of my variables have spaces in them. How do I make batch recognize the spaces?

Tags: batch-file

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (#opm2.txt) do @copy #input.txt %%A.txt

pause
```

That is my code. Basically, some of the lines in this file have spaces in them, but when the batch file is done running it doesn't output any of these lines. Is there a work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable the standard delims.
It could also a good idea to set the EOL-character to a colon, as a colon isn't a valid character for a file, but the standard EOL-character is (semicolon).
It's also necessary to quote the filename, when it can contain spaces

```
for /F "EOL=: tokens=* delims=" %%A in (#opm2.txt) do @copy #input.txt "%%A.txt"
```

Comment: It still appears that the thing won't accept spaces. Gives me 'The Syntax of the Command is not correct' on every line that has a space.

Comment: Ok, I forgott to quote the filename

Comment: Ah. Also, would it be possible to make it include special characters like -?

Thank you for the code, btw.

Comment: If you want to echo them, there is no problem, but they are not allowed for filenames